# Convert vertical sql result into horizontal output with Group by fields in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a table( in SQL Server 2008) which has vertical sales transactions data, i would like to convert vertical output to horizontal output, i tried to use PIVOT, but some how not getting idea how to apply group by on PIVOT, as i want Sum based on AccountHeadID, TransType and IsPast Column.

**Sample Table**

```
CREATE TABLE Trans
    ([TransID] int,
     [CustID] int,
     [AccountHeadID] int,
     [TransType] varchar(100),
     [IsPast] bit,
     [Amount] int)
;

INSERT INTO Trans
    ([TransID],CustID, [AccountHeadID], [TransType], [IsPast],[Amount])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 'Sales',1,1000),
    (2, 1, 1, 'Sales',0,500),
    (3, 1, 1, 'Sales',0,400),
    (4, 1, 1, 'Return',0,300),
    (5, 1, 1, 'Return',0,200),
    (6, 1, 1, 'Return',0,100),
    (7, 1, 1, 'Return',1,150),
    (8, 1, 2, 'Sales',1,2000)
```

**Current Query**

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(AccountHeadID)  
                    from Trans
                    group by AccountHeadID
                    order by AccountHeadID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT CustID,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              SELECT 
                a.CustID,
                a.AccountHeadID,
                 a.TransType,
                 a.Amount,
                 a.isPast
              FROM Trans a
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(Amount)
                for AccountHeadID in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

**Expected Output**

```
CustID | Account-HeadID-TransType-IsPast[1-Sales-Past] |  Account-HeadID-TransType-IsCurrent[1-Sales-Current] | Account-HeadID-TransType-IsCurrent[1-Return-Past] |  Account-HeadID-TransType-IsCurrent[1-Return-Current] | Account-HeadID-TransType-IsCurrent[2-Sales-Past]| ...
1      |1000                                           | 900 (500 + 400)                                      |150                                                | 600[300+200+100]                                       |2000
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4a68/6)

Any suggestion or input are most welcome!

Thanks
Suresh

Comment: Take a look at [a related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20836576/1810429) that may prove helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),AccountHeadID) + N'-' + TransType + N'-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),IsPast))  
                    from Trans
                    group by AccountHeadID, TransType, IsPast
                    order by AccountHeadID, TransType, IsPast
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

--select @cols

set @query = 'SELECT CustID,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              SELECT 
                a.CustID,
                CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),AccountHeadID) + N''-'' + TransType + N''-'' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),IsPast) Acct,
                 a.Amount
              FROM Trans a
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(Amount)
                for Acct in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4a68/21)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its perfect query!